# What is an SSID REALLY?

Tags: wifi, ssid

How do WiFi chips know that a signal is an SSID?

How are SSID’s encoded to denote their signal type?

What does it take to generate an SSID?

Do I need a WiFi card to GENERATE an SSID or can the be generated and broadcasted separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSID is an acronym meaning Service Set IDentifier, and is basically the (usually) human-readable name of a Wi-Fi network.

It is encoded in a few packets with ASCII characters, notably in almost every beacon and probe response packet (with a few exception, for example if the network is hidden).

So, being a name, generally it isn't "generated" but actually configured by someone, although in some cases it is automatically generated by an algorithm, for example in P2P applications such as a Wi-Fi printer with hotspot (or Wi-Fi Direct) capabilities. It is not a file, so it doesn't make sense for it to be generated and/or broadcasted.

I hope I catched your question, if not please clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: How would you generate an SSID using electronics? I'm not talking about how do I type in "My Network" into a router, I'm talking about in general, without a router. 
Would you need some software and an oscillator/antenna tuned to wifi freq's (2.4GHZ), etc? Or are there other ways to broadcast an SSID that nearby devices could read?

Comment: I guess you are referring to generating a beacon frame, then. Beacon frames are packets sent in the air by an access point (or in general a device broadcasting a Wi-Fi network): inside those frames there are a lot of information such as, for example, the MAC address of the AP, the SSID itself and general information about the AP's capabilities (see here https://mrncciew.com/2014/10/08/802-11-mgmt-beacon-frame/ for a more extensive explanation, or even better the IEEE 802.11 official documentation).

Comment: If you want to generate a "fake" beacon with something that is not an AP, you'd first need to choose one of the 802.11 standards (a/b/g/n/ac), build an electronic circuit capable of modulating bits using the modulation described in the standard you chose (for example, b is the simplest one as it uses BPSK) and then either send this circuit a pre-built stream of 1s and 0s according to the rules of beacon frames (see previously linked resources) or hardwire it in some way to your circuit.
It may be very hard to create something like this from scratch. If I may, what is your objective?

Comment: I was sitting in a pub, looking at the SSID's when I thought, "what a neat way to communicate with those in proximity". Hence the question.

Comment: If you only want that, you could use something like a RaspberryPi (either with integrated Wi-Fi antenna or with an external dongle) and Scapy. Scapy is a cross-platform tool that lets you generate Wi-Fi packets, and it's easy to use if you only want to generate a beacon frame. There's plently of tutorials about this on the internet, for example see https://www.4armed.com/blog/forging-wifi-beacon-frames-using-scapy/

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGLaA.png)

wifi follows 802.11 standard to send/receive wifi signal. 
Wifi Chip can knows AP's name (SSID) by AP's periodically broadcast signal called beacon.
If we sniffer wifi signal and decode it as above picture, there is an SSID IE which describes the name of AP. (e.g. openwrt-sae in this case)

Comment: Interesting. So it appears an SSID is a set of hex values that are broadcasted as part of a WiFi frame (I know that is too general). How would you craft one without a router?